# Footer is hovering right below content

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a pretty simple html page that I need to set up. I took inspiration from [this template](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_temp_social&stacked=h), and edited, until it started to reach my demands, and I now have the following html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="askStyles.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>    

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Watts social</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
      </ul>
 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container text-center">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 well">
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">Weekly usage</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>

        Did you save some cash? Buy a tree!
      </div>
      <table>
  
        <td>spent this week</td>
        <td>100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Saved</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yearly spending</td>
        <td>20000</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <form action="/action_page.php">
                <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50"> Update your status...
                  </textarea>
                  <br><br>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
              
              </button>     
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well yellow">
           <p>Christian Hvidekjær</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well neutral">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
            <div class="bottom-left-text">
              <span class="label label-default">KWH price: 200</span>
              <span class="label label-primary">Total KWH</span>
              <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
          </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well green">
           <p>Frederik Weis Holst</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well neutral">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
            <div class="bottom-left-text">
              <span class="label label-default">KWH price: 100</span>
              <span class="label label-primary">Total KWH: 200</span>
              <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
          </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well red" >
           <p>Carla Sørensen</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9" >
          <div class="well neutral">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
            <div class="bottom-left-text">
              <span class="label label-default">KWH price: 100</span>
              <span class="label label-primary">Total KWH: 200</span>
              <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

I also added my own little css file, just for supplementing:

```
  #footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5rem;            /* Footer height */
    margin-top: 19px;
  }
  body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

  .mytags {
    display:inline-block;
 }

 .red {
  background-color: #e21313;
}

.yellow {
background-color: #eaee19;
}

.green {
background-color: #0beb16;
}

.neutral {
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
```

In the original page (from we3schools) there is a footer that reaches both corners of the screen, but for some reason, in mine, it is only a small text in the bottom, floating right benath my other content:

[image]

This is pretty strange to me, and I cannot figure out which change that I have made that could have forced this. This being said, the footer in the "old" code also is floating and not fixed to the bottom, which I would like it to be.

So there's two things that I'm having trouble with:

1. getting my footer to reach both sides of the screen as a block
2. Having it fixed to the bottom.

**What I have tried**

I tried following [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page/) article, removing my already existing footer class, and making this one:

```
      #footer {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Height of the footer*/ 
    height: 40px;
    background: grey;
  }
```

This hasnt worked though.
This and a bunch of other articles really have'nt done the trick.

Any help would me much appreciated

**EDIT**

unclosed tags have now been fixed, thx. I have also updated code. The issue still persists

**EDIT 2**

thanks for the very good inputs, which have helped me in dispaying the footer again.
But still it's floating in the middle of the screen, I will also need to have it fixed

Comment: Some tags in you html files aren't properly closed, in you css you're using `#footer` where the `#` indicates an id not an element, also check bootstraps [container](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/) classes and how it affects elements width

Comment: From there you should have fewer problems achieving the expected behavior. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is happen because of style

```
body{
  display: flex;
}
```

But it could be not one reason.
It deform bootstrap styles and change footer appereance

In addition, if you add styles for id #footer you should add it to your html code

Answer (score 1):

You had a lot of tags not closed...you should be more careful.

Change the html like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="askStyles.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>    

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Watts social</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
      </ul>
 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container text-center">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 well">
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">Weekly usage</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>

        Did you save some cash? Buy a tree!
      </div>
      <p><a href="#">KWH price monthly: 500 dkkr </a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Total KWH </a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Click here to view good tips</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <form action="/action_page.php">
                <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50"> Update your status...
                  </textarea>
                  <br><br>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
              
              </button>     
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>      
      </div>
      </div>

      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well yellow">
           <p>Christian Hvidekjær</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well neutral">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
            <div class="bottom-left-text">
              <span class="label label-default">KWH price: 200</span>
              <span class="label label-primary">Total KWH</span>
              <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
          </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well green">
           <p>Frederik Weis Holst</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well neutral">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
            <div class="bottom-left-text">
              <span class="label label-default">KWH price: 100</span>
              <span class="label label-primary">Total KWH: 200</span>
              <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
          </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well red" >
           <p>Carla Sørensen</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9" >
          <div class="well neutral">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
            <div class="bottom-left-text">
              <span class="label label-default">KWH price: 100</span>
              <span class="label label-primary">Total KWH: 200</span>
              <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
          </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      </div>
<footer>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</div>

</footer>

<style>
  body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

  .mytags {
    display:inline-block;
 }

 .red {
  background-color: #e21313;
}

.yellow {
background-color: #eaee19;
}

.green {
background-color: #0beb16;
}

.neutral {
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
footer {background-color:gray}</style>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: thx a lot!! this does mess up the rest of my layout a bit though

Answer (score 1):

You had some mistakes on your html. For example, your `footer` was outside of `body` and some `div` tags not closed at all. I fixed those. And also added those lines for your purpose.

```
footer {
    /* get all available space */
    width: 100%;

    /* see visual change */
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;

    /* for better aligning */
    padding: 1em 0;
}
```

See complete example here.

```css
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5rem; /* Footer height */
    margin-top: 19px;
}
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.mytags {
    display: inline-block;
}

.red {
    background-color: #e21313;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: #eaee19;
}

.green {
    background-color: #0beb16;
}

.neutral {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

footer {
    /* get all available space */
    width: 100%;

    /* see visual change */
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;

    /* for better aligning */
    padding: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="askStyles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Watts social</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 well">
                <div class="well">
                    <p><a href="#">Weekly usage</a></p>
                </div>

                <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>

                    Did you save some cash? Buy a tree!
                </div>
                <p><a href="#">KWH price monthly: 500 dkkr </a></p>
                <p><a href="#">Total KWH </a></p>
                <p><a href="#">Click here to view good tips</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form action="/action_page.php">
                                    <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50"> Update your status...
                  </textarea>
                                    <br><br>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                </form>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="well yellow">
                            <p>Christian Hvidekjær</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="well neutral">
                            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot
                                something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
                            <div class="bottom-left-text">
                                <span class="label label-default">KWH price: 200</span>
                                <span class="label label-primary">Total KWH</span>
                                <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="well green">
                            <p>Frederik Weis Holst</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="well neutral">
                            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot
                                something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
                            <div class="bottom-left-text">
                                <span class="label label-default">KWH price: 100</span>
                                <span class="label label-primary">Total KWH: 200</span>
                                <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="well red">
                            <p>Carla Sørensen</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="well neutral">
                            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot
                                something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
                            <div class="bottom-left-text">
                                <span class="label label-default">KWH price: 100</span>
                                <span class="label label-primary">Total KWH: 200</span>
                                <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
        <p>Footer Text</p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thx! this does almost everything i want. My footer is still floating though.  Also the content in the middle is now floating to the left

Answer (score 0):

You had a few things happening here, I'll try to list them for you:

**IN YOUR HTML CODE**

1. Many unclosed tags, this was causing your `footer` element to be contained within multiple `div` tags
2. You still have a button closing tag but no associated opening tag (this is on line 68. I wasn't sure what you wanted here so left it as is.

**IN YOUR CSS CODE**

1. You referenced `#footer`. The `#` denotes an id whereas the footer element can simply be referenced as `footer`. No hashtag needed.
2. If you use `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` for your footer, it will load at the bottom of the screen and scroll up with your content as you navigate through the page. Removing these tags fixes this. Unnecessary, as well, since your `footer` elements rests outside of the `body` element.

I think that's everything. It would be worthwhile going through and comparing to your original code to see where I cleaned things up a bit and what's different as I may have missed something (apologies if so).

Here's the updated HTML and CSS!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="askStyles.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>    

  </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Watts social</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
      </ul>
 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container text-center">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 well">
      <div class="well">
        <p><a href="#">Weekly usage</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>

        Did you save some cash? Buy a tree!
      </div>
      <p><a href="#">KWH price monthly: 500 dkkr </a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Total KWH </a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Click here to view good tips</a></p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <form action="/action_page.php">
                <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50"> Update your status...
                  </textarea>
                  <br><br>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
              </form>
              
              </button>     
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well yellow">
           <p>Christian Hvidekjær</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well neutral">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
            <div class="bottom-left-text">
              <span class="label label-default">KWH price: 200</span>
              <span class="label label-primary">Total KWH</span>
              <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well green">
           <p>Frederik Weis Holst</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="well neutral">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
            <div class="bottom-left-text">
              <span class="label label-default">KWH price: 100</span>
              <span class="label label-primary">Total KWH: 200</span>
              <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well red" >
           <p>Carla Sørensen</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9" >
          <div class="well neutral">
            <p>Just Forgot that I had to mention something about someone to someone about how I forgot something, but now I forgot it. Ahh, forget it! Or wait. I remember.... no I don't.</p>
            <div class="bottom-left-text">
              <span class="label label-default">KWH price: 100</span>
              <span class="label label-primary">Total KWH: 200</span>
              <span class="label label-success">Labels</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5rem;            /* Footer height */
    margin-top: 19px;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.mytags {
    display:inline-block;
 }

.red {
  background-color: #e21313;
}

.yellow {
background-color: #eaee19;
}

.green {
background-color: #0beb16;
}

.neutral {
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: thx a lot for the tips. But it seems to me like the footer is in the same placement as before here